How to fill the gap between the exterior door frame and siding?
After new door frame installed, there is an approx. ¼ inch space gap between the siding and door frame.  Before installation, the frame was tight to the siding which is no longer the case.    Not sure if the frame was cut to short or frame just not the same size.  Either way, any ideas how best to handle the gap to keep out water and won’t look visually unpleasant?


Did you order & install the door or did you pay someone to do it? If you paid for it, finishing this should be on them.

Yes, I did pay somebody to do it.  Did an awesome job on another door I had but it was more patching.  This was replacing the frame and not sure what happened.   He will be returning tomorrow to hopefully get it fixed.   Cause yes, it should indeed be on them.  Thank you for the feedback.

At this point your best bet is probably a filler piece (PVC) and some poly sealant (e.g. OSI Quad Max).

I agree with Huesmann that a vinyl filler is a simple solution. I did just that when replacing 1950s windows with new flanged Andersen 400 casements, which left about a 1" gap to the siding channel. Some tips:

Purchase a molding with color and surface sheen matching the brickmold.

Rip it to the width of the gap with a mill finish edge outward. A table saw is your best bet so you have very straight edges.

Rip it to a depth that leaves it just behind the outer corner radius on the brickmold. Flush joints are challenging and usually don't look great. By leaving a reveal you add detail and make precise fitment less critical.

Lap the head (top) piece over the sides for best appearance and to follow a typical weatherproofing strategy.

Install with just caulk. Place a bead on the outside face of the brick mold and on another on the house wrap. Do not caulk against the J-channel, as vinyl siding moves a lot. Press it in place. Hold for a few hours with masking tape if it's not staying put on its own. Caulk the ends where the new pieces lap each other.

Strive to avoid any caulk on the surface, as it'll collect dirt and may yellow with age. If anything, use a very small bead between the brick mold and filler—just enough to fill any gap—and tool it off cleanly.


Polyurethane caulk is indeed one of the most grabby and durable options. It also doesn't shrink as much as acrylic latex, for example. Note that it's quite tenacious on hands, clothes, etc., so plan well and work carefully to keep it only where you want it.
Also note that vinyl which has been ripped into thin strips and has had three of its faces removed gets a bit brittle. Don't over-flex it. If it's snug, press it in slowly along the entire length.
